# Existing file in tmp folder not detected by application running using apache2 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, python, apache2

I have the following python code deployed on server running under apache2 with ubuntu 20.04:

```
import os
print(os.path.exists("/tmp/test.csv"))
```

above code returns `False` even though the test.csv file exists. However if i run the same code not under apache like as a normal python script it returns `True`.

Here are the permission of tmp folder and the file:

```
drwxrwxrwt  45 root www-data            12288 Mar 19 18:09 tmp

-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data         0 Mar 19 17:25 test.csv
```

This was working fine on ubuntu 18.04 the problem has occurred since we upgraded to 20.04.

Edit:

I had tried adding tmp directory in `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`
with read and write permission and then restarting the apparmor `/etc/init.d/apparmor restart`
but that did nothing.

Comment: Remove the first `/` from `/tmp/test.csv` unless that file exists all the way off of the root of the drive in the actual `/tmp` folder.  Make it look like `tmp/test.csv`

Comment: Apache is not permitted to read or write data outside of `/var/www` by default. If you want Apache to access files from elsewhere, you’ll need to modify Apache’s AppArmor profile to include specific directories 

Comment: @matigo I had tried that already by adding tmp directory in `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` with read and write permission and then restarting the apparmor `/etc/init.d/apparmor restart
` but that did nothing.

Comment: @Terrance Thanks for your valuable comment but i fixed it please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a solution:

Ubuntu 20.04 comes with a latest version of apache which has a `PrivateTmp` variable that creates a separate `tmp` directory in different namespace. So when I was creating a file in global `tmp` directory (which is available to all processes) apache was looking for the file in its private tmp directory and hence was not able to find it. check [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#PrivateTmp=) for more.

The solution was to set `PrivateTmp` to false in `vi /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service` and then reload the demon process `systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: Thank you. this one works for me. I tried with Ubuntu Apache2

Comment: Glad it helped you.